# ifstream read binary data issue 0x00 byte

Tags: c++, io, binary, fstream, ifstream

Hi everyone i have an issue while reading binary data from a binary file as following:

File Content:
D3 EE EE 00 00 01 D7 C4 D9 40

```
char * afpContentBlock = new char[10];
ifstream inputStream(sInputFile, ios::in|ios::binary);

if (inputStream.is_open()))
{
    inputStream.read(afpContentBlock, 10);

    int n = sizeof(afpContentBlock)/sizeof(afpContentBlock[0]); // Print 4

    // Here i would like to check every byte, but no matter how i convert the 
    // char[] afpContentBlock, it always cut at first byte 0x00.
}
```

I know this happens cause of the byte 0x00. Is there a way to manage it somehow ?
I have tried to write it with an ofstream object, and it works fine since it writes out the whole 10 bytes. Anyway i would like to loop through the whole byte array to check bytes value.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The usual reply is "why aren't you using `vector`?" (and I'm quite certain `sizeof(afpContentBlock)/sizeof(afpContentBlock[0])` is not 7, but 4 or 8).

Comment: I had fixed the file content (it was wrong).A code snippet would really be helpful and appreciated since i am really not used yet to vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier to just get how many bytes you read from the ifstream like so:

```
if (inputStream.is_open()))
{
   inputStream.read(afpContentBlock, 10);
   int bytesRead = (int)inputStream.gcount();

   for( int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++ )
   {
      // check each byte however you want
      // access with afpContentBlock[i]
   }
}
```

Comment: @Duncan_McCloud You're right, edited to fix that. Been a while lol.